# how is common to retrieve id from database for information deletion

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete some data from database with post method , but I can't make up my mind how to retrieve id of element for complete marked action. here is php script =>

```
<?php
echo "<form action='index.php' name='del_file_f' id='del_file_f' method='post'>";
                            echo "<table>";
                                for ($i=0;$i<$get_r->num_rows;$i++){
                                    $get_row = $get_r->fetch_assoc();

                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><p>" . $get_row['f_title'] . "." . $get_row['file_ext'] . "</p></td>";
                                        echo "<td><a href='" . $config->host . "/" . constant("FILE_PLACE") . "/" . $get_row['doc_folder'] . "/" . $get_row['doc_name'] . "." . $get_row['file_ext'] . "'><div class='img_down'></div></a><input type='hidden' name='del_file_" . $i . "' value='" . $get_row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' class='alink' id='" . $i . "'><div class='img_del'></div></a></td>";
                                        echo "<td><p>" . $get_row['f_size'] . "</p></td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                            echo "</table>";
                        echo "</form>";
?>
```

and I am trying action within hidden element which's name is unknown because of number of row, I need just to know this name for accomplish this task , any ideas how to get information of this name ? or how to get `$get_row['id']` (it is id of row in mysql database) known for each row ? thanks

**UPDATE**

for more simpler , when data is retrieved from database , it will look like this =>

file name |  download | file size | delete img |

one       | some link | 2mb       |  anchor    |

etc

I just want to be able to delete desired data from this selection , and for this purpose I need to know id of hidden element , which's name is also unknown . If i set hidden element name to fix name , it will override to others .

Comment: Not sure i understand the question, but, print_r($_POST) will show you what values you have to work with

Comment: Also you might want to provide an array of elements. See PHP FAQ about that: [How do I create arrays in a HTML <form>?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: How you saw from the script I have anchor , with javascript I am making this anchor like a submit , so I need to know hidden element value to accomplish my task. My question is simple , just want to get hidden element value (which is id of row)

Comment: sorry, your English is terrible, with a technical subject its just to hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Dagon sorry for my English . To say more simpler , I am trying to delete some data from database which I know how to do ,just can not make up my mind how to get the id of the row known for each retrieved row , which is value of the hidden element

Comment: @Dagon maybe now can understand question well , pls see :)

Comment: your $_POST array will have a key of del_file_# use that

Comment: @Dagon I know, but in this situation I do not know this `#` exact number, here is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
echo "<td><a href='" . $config->host . "/" . constant("FILE_PLACE") . "/" . $get_row['doc_folder'] . "/" . $get_row['doc_name'] . "." . $get_row['file_ext'] . "'><div class='img_down'></div></a><input type='hidden' name='del_file_" . $i . "' value='" . $get_row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' class='alink' id='" . $i . "'><div class='img_del'></div></a></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href='" . $config->host . "/" . constant("FILE_PLACE") . "/" . $get_row['doc_folder'] . "/" . $get_row['doc_name'] . "." . $get_row['file_ext'] . "'><div class='img_down'></div></a><input type='hidden' name='del_file[]' value='" . $get_row['id'] . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' class='alink' id='" . $i . "'><div class='img_del'></div></a></td>";
```

then you will have a post array $_POST['del_file'] with each key, you can then loop through with a foreach like so:

```
foreach($_POST['del_file'] as $i){

//delete mysql using $i as the row id
}
```